# Hibernate mapping for SQL Server 'Date' datatype

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm facing a problem in my project. Actually I'm using Hibernate with SQL Server 2008.
One of my DB table contains attributes with 'date' data type. The problem is, how to map that attribute with java property (string type). Suppose input coming in the form of a string eg '2012-04-25'. How to do that? Its urgent.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you wouldn't map it to a `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar`?

Comment: I map it with Date. Works Fine. Thanx @beny23

Answer (score 1):

Write a user type.

[Here](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/11/09/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/) is some more information about it.